# Looking for a high quality (UK) summer ambience

Tags: exchange, ambience, recording

I hope people don't mind me posting a request, say so if you do. But I think that exchanging sounds is part of being in a community :-)

Anyway, I'm stuck in South Africa and in winter, but for a project I'm working on I'm in need of a typical summer UK ambience. What does this mean? Well I'm not so sure but it needs to be as authentic as possible. I'm picturing birds, cicadas/crickets, and general summer goodness. If it was free of traffic that would be a bonus! If no luck, it doesn't have to be UK, any summer ambience would be awesome, I know that the south of France where I'm from has a hugely distinct sound, which would work great too!

Anyway, if anyone has got a top quality stereo summer ambience and would like to exchange it for another sound or sell it or donate, please let me know! I only really need 10 to 15 seconds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just mentioned the website on the resources list but you might find it specifically useful.

http://www.soundsnap.com/search/audio/rural+england/score

I use Soundsnap fairly frequently, especially finding authentic atmoses from around the world, which I've been doing so for a show recently.

I've got a recording from the New Forest, although it has some plane noise if you'd like me to send it to you?

Comment: haha, straight after posting my question I started searching on soundsnap. Yes, I would love to hear your recording if you don't mind. andrew [at] soundplusdesign [dot] com Thanks so much!

Comment: I made this recording while still at Uni many years ago. I've not heard it for years and quite frankly it's really not a very good recording, sorry Andrew. If you're still stuck I've just ordered a ZoomH1 and could get you one when I go home to see my folks at the beginning of Sept. Deepest Darkest Wiltshire! Going to get some sounds anyway on my trip. Sorry sir.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Andrew.

I am UK based (South East UK).  I have been out and about a lot this summer recording ambiances around a small coastal town in Sussex.  During these sessions I have visited a nearby nature reserve and have collected a number of Nature sounds.

One of the recordings I think you might be particularly interested in are of insects (crickets etc..) in a marsh land.

There may be a few others that may interest you aswell.

If you're still looking for the sounds please get in touch :).

Answer (score 2):

The BBC's Save Our Sounds project is really cool for finding location specific sounds!
http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/specialreports/saveoursounds/index.shtml

So is the website soundtransit
http://soundtransit.nl/search/

Comment: Thanks, love these websites. But sadly, I don't think I can download these streams and if I could, the quality is not up to scratch for my needs. Thanks very much for the suggestion though!  

Answer (score 1):

Hi Andrew,

I'm from the UK but am currently based in the South of France and have recently recorded the cicadas out here, which are pretty much THE sound of summer in this part of the world! You'd be more than welcome to use them if that would help?

As for being genuine, it's difficult to say too much without knowing more about the footage you'll be putting this to but to be honest, due to the climate being generally a bit cold in the UK (even in summer) the countryside sounds are more about birds and bees than crickets. If it's a really hot summer then they may be heard but it's no way as prominent than in the South of France.

Anyway, you can check out the cicada recording at http://soundcloud.com/colin-hunter/cicadas-loop

Hope this helps and let me know if you want to use the recording and I'll email it to you...

Colin

Comment: Oh awesome! Thanks. That's just the sound from my youth. Nice recording. It might make a good layer although I'll have to check with the director if it's maybe too unauthentic. Do you by any chance have a slightly longer piece? 

Comment: Yep I've got some longer recordings. That was a short loop but I'll email you a couple of longer ones to your sound plus design address... 

Answer (score 1):

I would think that something like this would be easily found in the BBC FX library. It may be slightly old, but the bird/ambience recordings in that library are top notch.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own it :-( But maybe a studio around the area does. Thanks for the tip. 

Comment: Hah! I'm having the copy I discovered where I work digitised as it's on DAT. I'll have a look through the list and get them to record that tape for you if you like?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you found what you were after, I did try to record some now that the sun is back but I'm not geared up properly, the only stereo mic I have is the one built in my Tascam DR100 and to get usable levels there's too much self noise with the gain.

If not, tell me, I'll try a little harder ;)

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay, been away on a job. Thanks so much for the offer! Don't go out of your way to record something for me, please. If you have something already that might work then awesome, if not really don't worry. The project is almost done, I've sent it all already, although there is room for last minute adjustment, but I'm happy with what I already have. Thanks again! 

Comment: @Andrew, no worries, I made a few recordings on my way home because it was the occasion for me to test my recorder ;) Hope all went well!